# What exactly does configuring Windows Defender Firewall to allow/forbid an app to communicate on private/public networks do?

Tags: networking, firewall

I've installed some app, let's say Syncthing, on my Windows computer. When I run it for the first time, Windows Defender Firewall notifies me:

> Windows Defender Firewall has blocked some features of this app
>
> Windows Defender Firewall has blocked some features of Syncthing on all public and private networks.
>
> Name: ...
>
> Publisher: ...
>
> Path: ...
>
> Allow Syncthing to communicate on these
>
> [✓] Private networks, such as my home or work network
>
> [✓] Public networks, such as those in airports and cafes

What happens if I allow or forbid the app to communicate on public/private networks? Does this affect only the ability of the app to open ports and receive incoming connections? Does this also forbid the app to use the internet at all when it's connected using the chosen network? Does this affect whether the app can trigger UPNP on the router? Anything else?

Answer (score 1):

The Private and Public tags are attributes that you have assigned to
any new network to which you connect.

Private network is usually your home or office; Public network is
typically a coffee-shop or a hotel via WiFi. In Public networks,
other computers cannot connect to your computer.

When a new program attempts to connect to the outside for the
first time, Windows asks whether to block its outgoing connections
completely, or only block them on Public networks, or not to block
at all.

With this dialog, you decide which permissions to assign to this
new program, as a function of the trust that you place in it.

Comment: So, you're saying that incoming connections are always blocked on public networks while outgoing connections are blocked or not blocked depending on this firewall rule?

Comment: Yes, and depending also on other rules and parameters that you have set.